# How to move the elements of list box up and down after displaying their properties?

Tags: c#

I created a code wherein when i select an item in a list box, the info about the item gets displayed in a text box. I also have move up and down buttons to move the contents of the list up and down and delete button to delete the selected item. Now when i click on the item the info is getting displayed in the text box but if i click on move up, down or delete button for the same item then exception is thrown Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The line that throws this exception is when i am creating a new object of ClassName in the code below:

```
    private void lb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_Txt.Clear();
        ClassName fileInfo = new ClassName(m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedItem.ToString());
        m_Txt.Multiline = true;
        m_Txt.Text = fileInfo.title + Environment.NewLine + fileInfo.ID + Environment.NewLine + fileInfo.time;

    }
```

the code for move up button is:

```
    private void m_btnUP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedIndex != 0 && m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
          //  m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedItem.
            object item = m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedItem;
            int index = m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedIndex;
            m_lbOPFfiles.Items.RemoveAt(index);

            m_lbOPFfiles.Items.Insert(index - 1, item);
        }         
    }
```

Please tell what possibly could be the problem and the solution for it.

Comment: You did notice the system with votes and accepted answers on stackoverflow.com? ;o)

Answer (score 1):

SelectedIndexChanged is fired when an item is selected, but also when an item is "unselected" (which would happen if the currently selected item is removed from the list). Add a check to verify that there is an item selected:

```
if (m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedIndex >= 0)  // you can also use m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedItem != null
{
    m_Txt.Clear();
    ClassName fileInfo = new ClassName(m_lbOPFfiles.SelectedItem.ToString());
    m_Txt.Multiline = true;
    m_Txt.Text = fileInfo.title + Environment.NewLine + fileInfo.ID + Environment.NewLine +  fileInfo.time;
}
```

If no item is selected SelectedIndex is -1, and SelectedItem is null.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be on the 3rd line of the `lb_SelectedIndexChanged` method.
You are calling `ToString()` on the `SelectedItem` which might be null at this point - after removing the item in line 7 of the `m_btnUP_Click` method it probably is null - and this will throw you the exception.

You can see in the exception details which line of code it was thrown from, and pin point the error like this. You can also debug the code line by line and see for yourself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your `Items.RemoveAt` call is clearing the selection, causing `SelectedItem` to become `null`, and the `lb_SelectedIndexChanged` event to fire, where this `null` causes the problem you describe.

I suggest you make sure in the event handler that something is actually selected.